# Items of a list: Should I capitalize them and use a period at the end?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, capitalization, list

In English, the items of a list are written like in the following sentence.

> I have done all my today's jobs:
>
> - Prepared breakfast for the family
> - Made sure everybody was awake in time for doing what they had to do
> - Washed the dishes from the previous night's dinner
> - Cleaned home
> - Prepared lunch for me, and dinner for everybody

How should I write the same sentence in Italian? Should I capitalize every item in the list? Should I avoid adding a period at the end of each item? In the case the single items are sentences, should I add the period at the end of each sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general idea is that you are completing the first part of the sentence before the list, so punctuation goes with it. Example:

> Lavorare con noi ti permette di
>
> - andare a casa ogni giorno alle cinque,
> - avere pranzo gratis e
> - ricevere una gratificazione natalizia.

As you can see it's a *typographical convention over a correct, Italian sentence*.
Another example:

> Ecco i benefit che offriamo:
>
> - 30 giorni di ferie all'anno;
> - assicurazione sanitaria privata;
> - due monitor per sviluppatore.

Similarly, it still reads as a sentence (albeit a boring, long, list-like one using [semicolons to separate concepts](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_e_virgola)). A different case in which lists are composed of sentences:

> Ecco alcune domande che potremmo chiederti:
>
> - Quanti dì conta novembre?
> - Di che colore era il cavallo bianco di Napoleone?
> - Come si neutralizza il fantasma Formaggino?

In this case, everything still reads as normal Italian, but each sentence is capitalized and ends with a punctuation mark (in this case a question mark, but periods and exclamation marks also work).

Answer (score 8):

The common style is to use a semicolon at the end of every list item, and start items with lowercase letters.

There is an alternative style, ending each sentence with a full stop and starting each item with a capital letter.

They can be both used. It depends mainly on the publisher (for books, magazines and newspapers).